# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jqmcvi'

Tags: python, pip

I get this error when I try the below code

```
from jqmcvi import base
```

After getting this error, I have tried

```
pip install jqmcvi
```

But then also I get the following error-

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jqmcvi
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jqmcvi
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Comment: Clone the github repo. & install using `python setup.py install`

Comment: Or just use `pip install git+repo_path.git`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library you are trying to install is NOT listed and maintained in PyPI. You can search for the libraries [here](https://pypi.org/).

If not listed, you can still install the library directly from git using pip as (at your own risk) -

```
pip install git+https://github.com/jqmviegas/jqm_cvi.git
```

You will git the path to the project available from the github repo of the library.

[image]

Once done, you may want to restart your kernel once.

---

You can otherwise clone the repo, go to the folder and then use `python setup.py install`

```
#cd into a folder
git clone https://github.com/jqmviegas/jqm_cvi jqmcvi

#cd into the folder of repo
python setup.py install
```

Comment: It's not working. It gives a very long error-
Collecting git+https://github.com/jqmviegas/jqm_cvi.git
  Cloning https://github.com/jqmviegas/jqm_cvi.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-lvv4krg6
Building wheels for collected packages: jqmcvi
  Building wheel for jqmcvi (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Comment: ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-2dfde58bf526> in <module>
----> 1 from jqmcvi import base

ImportError: cannot import name 'base' from 'jqmcvi' (unknown location)


Thanks. It did solve my previous error. Can you please help with this error?

Comment: Hi, do raise another SO question for the new error, other people can help contribute to it as well :)

Comment: Getting this error: `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-dxbug3cq/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-dxbug3cq/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-hdnxwt3b/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.`

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about [this project](https://github.com/jqmviegas/jqm_cvi)?  If so, it does not appear to be in the Python Package Index (PyPi) where pip goes by default to look for packages.  Instead, you will need to clone the repositorty and follow the installation instructions outlined in the README in the repository.  Once you install it from source, it should be available to you to import.